# The app Stack Exchange crashes on iPad

Tags: ipad, applications

I have an iPad 3 with iOS version 8.3 and the lastest version of the Stack Exchange app. It's very difficult to use the app because it crashes always, e.g. when I scraping the answers to a questions,when I go to my profile and so on. What is the reason and can be solved?

Comment: Latest App Store version or latest beta version of the Stack Exchange app? Preferably can you provide the exact version number? (Open the app's side menu and scroll above your username.) Can you provide a crash log?

Comment: The lastest App Store version, the 1.6.5.4. For the crash log, what do I do on iPad?

Comment: This is quite similar to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290875/stack-exchange-app-keeps-crashing) on the stack exchange meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Crash logs are automatically reported to developers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236741/339911). So there is no need to do it manually.

To prevent crashing you could try any of Crash Recovery options from iOS system settings:

> [image: recovery]

Another problem may be due to you using old iOS version. See Brian's answer for another question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290175/339911).

Pulled from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290875/stack-exchange-app-keeps-crashing)